# Recall Method - how to?

Tags: android

I have start activity "A" which call all method in that activity. Then navigating from A to another activity let say "B". I am finishing "B" activity but "A" activity method does not get called. How to recall "A" activity methods after finishing "B" activity

Comment: Call A activity after B Finished .

Comment: read the activity life cycle https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html

Comment: why calling A? it is default to return to activity A after B is destoryed or finished. Because B is called from A.

Answer (score 0):

Just **override** *onResume* method on your "A" activity and do whatever you want there.

Answer (score 0):

Use below flow to get what you trying to do :

Here there are two methods like wise you can create any number of methods , what i'm doing here when launches **Activity_A** all methods run because now i have two methods which will run because these two methods are calling by `onCreate`,

When you call **Activity_B** from **Activity_A** then **Activity_A** will be in Pause  state,
so when you will finish **Activity_B** , **Activity_A** call their `onResume();` first , call that method from `onResume();`

Understand the flow of Activity LifeCycle :

[image]

**Activity_A.java**

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_a);

       init(); //this is method
       everyTimeCall(); //this is method
    }

 private void init() {
   //code here
 }

 private void everyTimeCall() {
      //code here
 }

protected void onResume() {
     super.onResume();
     everyTimeCall();// when came from Activity_B this method calls
}
```

**Activity_B.java**

`onBackPress()` or `finish()`

Comment: thanks for answring my question. Pleas up vote my question

Comment: If you solved your issue by my answer, Don't forget to accept my Answer@reshma

Answer (score 0):

First read the Activity lifecycle methods [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html). If you want to call some methods that you created you can override `onResume()` method in Activity "A" but that will be called multiple times or you can use `startActivityForResult()` to start Activity "B" and in Activity "B" before calling `finish()` use `setResult()` method. In Activity "A" override `onActivityResult()` method and call your methods again that you want to call. Check the documentation for `startActivityForResult()`[here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)